# Why is char acting as int in for loop?

Tags: c, winavr

```
#include "avr/io.h"
main()   
{ 
 unsigned char= z  ;  
 for(z=0;z<200;z++) 
  PORTA=z;  //PORTA dispalys the value of z
}
```

Please explain the working of the loop as z is char and is acting as int

Comment: Please explain *what* about the code. Why it doesn't compile?

Comment: what i meant was...that how come a char data type can be incremented...for example if i have a char variable like char c=9; and if i increment it what would be the next value....whether it would be an ascii value or 10.....and one more thing this code works absolutely fine...i just had doubt...i hope i have made my question more clearer to you...

Comment: `unsigned char= z  ;` compiles? A char data type can be incremented because it's really just a byte.

Answer (score 1):

`char` (and by extension, `unsigned char`) is an integral type.  An `unsigned char` can hold values from 0 to 255.

Characters are typically stored in `char` variables as well.  What they actually store is the ASCII value of the character in question.  For example:

```
char c = 'A';
```

The variable `c` contains the value 65, which is the ASCII value of `A`.

In the case of this code, an `unsigned char` variable is being used in an integer context.

Comment: The range is the minimum range. The standard does not specify an upper bound for `UCHAR_MAX`. Strictly speaking, something like `A` is an [_integer character constant_](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p2) and has type `int`.